# Installing clipspy on linux build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_clips.c:523:19: fatal error: clips.h: No such file or directory #include <clips.h>

Tags: linux, clips, clipspy

can someone give a step by step procedure on how to install clips and then clipspy in a linux environment. `pip install clipspy` does not works for me as pip is not allowed in my organization. I need to build from source.

I tried `python setup.py install` from `clipspy-0.3.0` but compilation terminated.

```
gcc -pthread -B /anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes /clips_core_source_630/core/ -fPIC -Ic -Itmpclips_core_source_630core -I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_clips.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_clips.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_clips.c:523:19: fatal error: clips.h: No such file or directory
 #include <clips.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I understand I'll have to install clips_6.30 but there are many make files in src code

> clips_core_source_630/makefiles> ls
>
> makefile.g++  makefile.gcc  makefile.lib  makefile.lib++  makefile.win

I am not experienced in `c/c++` technologies and not able to understand various makefiles present in `clips_core_source_630`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at `clipspy` [travis installation](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/blob/master/.travis_install.sh) script for a reference example.

Once you extract the CLIPS archive you can copy the `makefile.lib` file in the source folder.

You then need to slightly modify the Makefile to build CLIPS as shared library. To do so, add the `-fPIC` flag to the `gcc` compile command. This will produce several `.o` files suitable for inclusion in a library.

Use the `make` command to build the sources.
You can then link the object files together to produce the library file.

```
ld -G *.o -o libclips.so
```

Once done, you can build and install `clipspy`, make sure you have up-to-date `cffi` and `setuptools` Python modules.

```
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs <clips_dir>/core/ --library-dirs <clips_dir>/core/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: thanks! as one last step I had to move libclips.so to anaconda3/lib (which is set to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: Unfortunately, shared libraries and headers locations differ between distributions as well as for their location mechanisms. So your command is very specific to your setup. Glad you sorted it out anyways.